# How to get true or false from PHP function using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tested **status.php** return value with var_dump($result) and alerted it out in check() function like this:

```
function check() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "status.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

and it did return true or false depending on situation, but when I check if data is true or false inside of check() function it always returns false.

**status.php:**

```
<?php 
function status(){
    if(logged() === true) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
status();
?>
```

**check() function:** always alerts "false" even though sometimes should be "true"

```
function check() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "status.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data === true){
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I doubt it return anything because there is no echo in php so nothing will be sendback to browser in ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not sending the return value of the `status()` function back to PHP. Use:

```
echo json_encode(status());
```

And change the AJAX call to expect a JSON response.

```
function check() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "status.php",
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: also note that `var_dump` or json_encode would be string so won't pass `=== true` comparison

Comment: `"I tested status.php return value with var_dump($result)"`

Comment: I assumed that was just temporary debugging, it's gone now.

Answer (score 2):

you just echo the $result like this

ajax not returning value so that we have to echo it.

```
 <?php function status(){
if(logged() === true) {
    $result = true;
} else {
    $result = false;
}
echo $result;  } status();  ?>
```

and then  should be like this

```
function check() {
$.ajax({
    url: "status.php"
}).done(function(data) {
    if(data == "true"){
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
});   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
**dataType: 'json'** 
function check() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "status.php",
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

and on status.php use

```
echo json_encode(status());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the response by return method in ajax. to get value "echo" whatever the result in the function , like

```
function status(){
    if(logged() === true) {
        $result = "1";
    } else {
        $result = "0";
    }
    echo $result;exit;
}
```

you will get the value 1 or 0 in your ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

Ajax may not be returning a boolean `true` or `false`, rather a string.

So try and put `true` in double quotes:

`if(data=="true")`

You can also use the `trim` function on data to ensure no whitespace is present in the returned data, like so:

`if($.trim(data)=="true")`

Comment: The AJAX isn't returning anything, since there's no `echo` in the PHP.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. You can use echo $result instead of $return result in status.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove Type checking i.e '===' replace with '=='

```
function check() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "status.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data == true){
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
}
```