# how to test data returned with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing a simple ajax call where I test an input value then return `true` or `false`. If it is `false` then I wanna change the input color to red
my ajax code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {
                    id1: $(this).val(),
                    id2: $(this).attr('id')
                    },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data == false) {
                    $('#'+id2+'').addClass( 'red' );
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my test.php is like this

```
require_once('index.php');
$x=intval($_POST['id1']);
$yy=intval($_POST['id2']);
$output= tester($x,$yy);
echo $output;
function tester($x,$y){
    if($solutions[$y]==$x)
        return true;
    else
        echo false;
}
```

This code works fine without `if` statement. I wanna test data to added a class that change input color into red. But, this code don't work for me.

Comment: use php's `json_encode()` and javascript's `JSON.parse()`

Comment: why are you doing echo instead of return for false ? echo is just going to print false, not return the response as false

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810391/how-to-get-true-or-false-from-php-function-using-ajax

Comment: i changed to return but still nothing, the link you gave me didnt fix my problem, what i wanna do is an if statment test

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.parse :

```
if(JSON.parse(data) == false) {
     $('#'+id2+'').addClass( 'red' );
 }
```

And in your php add json_encode() and return your false :

```
$yy=intval($_POST['id2']);
$output= tester($x,$yy);
echo json_encode($output);
function tester($x,$y){
    if($solutions[$y]==$x)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

}
```

Comment: thank you but it dont work, im not getting thed red color

Comment: Did you check the error? error:function(err){ alert(err) }

Comment: i just checked the console log, the response is a full html page; is that normal?

Comment: Did you add <?php ?> to your php file?

Comment: But not it's not normal

Comment: ofcourse, i tried now to remove the rquire once but im still getting like an html page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133499/discussion-between-messi-adrinho-and-charly-berthet).